# plotting data with two conditions

Tags: pgfplots

I can plot data depending on the value in one column like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
a,b,c,d
0,0,1,2
2,2,1,2
3,-3,1,3
2,1,2,4
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot+[only marks]
    table[x=a, y=b, col sep=comma,
      restrict expr to domain={\thisrow{c}}{1:1}]{data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to apply two conditions?  For example, I would like to plot data where both the value in c = 1 and the value in d = 2 without plotting data where only one applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `x expr` to apply the conditions. If the result is not true, set the x value to `nan`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
a,b,c,d
0,0,1,2
2,2,1,2
3,-3,1,3
2,1,2,4
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot+[only marks]
    table[
      x expr={and(\thisrow{c}==1,\thisrow{d}==2)==1?\thisrow{a}:nan},
      y=b,
      col sep=comma,
      ]{data.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  And for anyone wanting three conditions, this seems to work: `x expr={and(\thisrow{c}==1,and(\thisrow{a}==0,\thisrow{d}==2))==1?\thisrow{a}:nan},`